# Why does tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose need no output_shape compared to tf.nn.conv2d_transpose?

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, transpose, autoencoder, tensorflow2.0

I am missing something basic here. But I always used the `tf.nn` API for transpose convolution, where I have to specify the output shape, because it is ambiguous([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43624625/why-do-we-have-to-specify-output-shape-during-deconvolution-in-tensorflow/43624992#43624992)). 
However, for TF 2.0 I switch to Keras sub-classing and now I wonder why I do not have to specify the output shape for transpose convolution in the higher level API. How to they compute it exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranpose` backends to `tf.nn.conv2d_transpose` via `tf.keras.backend.conv2d_transpose`.

To compute the `output_shape` argument for `tf.nn.conv2d_transpose` it utilizes the function `deconv_output_length` (defined [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/layers/utils.py)):

```
def deconv_output_length(input_length, filter_size, padding, stride):
  """Determines output length of a transposed convolution given input length.
  Arguments:
      input_length: integer.
      filter_size: integer.
      padding: one of "same", "valid", "full".
      stride: integer.
  Returns:
      The output length (integer).
  """
  if input_length is None:
    return None
  input_length *= stride
  if padding == 'valid':
    input_length += max(filter_size - stride, 0)
  elif padding == 'full':
    input_length -= (stride + filter_size - 2)
  return input_length
```